# Books in applied Online Optimization

Tags: reference-request, books

What are books on [Online Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_optimization) other than Introduction to Online Convex Optimization?

Preferably:

- more on applied side, rather than theoretical
- not limited to convex only

Comment: you know [Online Optimization of Large Scale Systems](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540424598)?

Comment: I like [Online Computation and Competitive Analysis](https://www.amazon.de/Online-Computation-Competitive-Analysis-Borodin/dp/0521563925)